# I am trying to build docker image for python scripting language using Visual Studio code; but facing a problem when I used touch app.py command

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, docker-image

In terminal I wrote following command.

Step-1: cd Desktop
Step-2: mkdir python-docker
Step-3: cd python-docker
Step-4: pip3 install Flask
Step-5: pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
Step-6: $ touch app.py

Note: when I typed the code "touch app.py" in terminal, I am getting following error.
touch : The term 'touch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- touch app.py
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (touch:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Looks like you're on Windows? `touch` is a Linux command

Comment: @Shah Alam -Have you tried to test this process in a terminal outside of VS Code? In addition to creating files using commands, we can also create "app.py" files manually in VS Code.

Comment: So, you mean, touch command is used to create app.py file. Am I right?

Comment: @Shah Alam -The Linux touch command is used to modify the time attributes of a file or directory, including access time and change time. If the file does not exist, the system will create a new file.